# Where are my files after git add .?

Tags: bitbucket

I run the command:

```
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git add .
```

Then the screen gave me the information.
[image: git-add]

I think that the files were added to the remote cloud. But why I can't find them in my bitbucket account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is not correct.

Modified files are not committed in this case.

You should add those files **before** committing to BitBucket

```
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
```

Study the guide for a better understanding.
[Basics of Working in Local Repository Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/_Basics+of+Working+in+Local+Repository+Git)

Comment: It seems okay. The screen flashed a lot; `create mode blah`. Where can I check them in BitBucket? I still did not locate them.

Comment: @Love You can find the commits in https://bitbucket.org/ACCOUNTNAME/PROJECT/commits/all.

Comment: -@Ivan, It gave me `I have no commits, rendering me useless...`

Comment: @Love Did you run `git push origin` after committing?

Comment: @Love Have you followed the procedure listed here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Create+a+repository

Comment: @IvanChau, I am kind of frustrate and ready to give up. `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: @Love Try `git remote rm origin` then `git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/REPONAME.git` Finally `git push -u origin --all`

Comment: @IvanChau, eventually it was committed. Your `rm` command is very useful. I tried a few times then success. It seems sometimes Bitbucket like a drunk man with slow response. Anyway thanks.